# C# replace quotes

Tags: c#

I am iterating some db values through a c# script. Now I have the problem, that if the db value is "" (only 2 quotes) that c# expects some expressions or a semicolon. What can I do to avoid this? If there is a value like "" I would like to skip it.

I have tried something like this, but it did not work:

```
sVal.Replace(@"""", "");
```

or

```
if (sVal != @"""") ...
```

Thanks.

Comment: How are you reading these strings that makes `""` cause problems? Could you provide some context on what it is you're doing with `sVal`. Are you using it in a query or is it the result of the query? Also `@""""` is only one quote. The outer quotes are for the string and the inner two are ONE quote under @.

Comment: FYI strings are immutable. Replace returns a new string so you need to assign the result to something.

Comment: Why would double quotes be a problem? What is your *actual* code, *actual* error message? Are you constructing queries by concatenating stings? That's a *very* bad idea that exposes you to SQL injection problems and conversion issues precisely because parts of the data end up into the query itself. No amount of quoting and escaping can solve this. It's a lot easier (and faster) to use parameterized queries

Comment: Your code is replacing all instances of double quotes, not just two double quotes with nothing between them. You'd need to use `@""""""` or `"\"\""`. But you haven't described what you mean by *"it did not work"*. Please edit your question to add sample code that reproduces the issue, including input string and expected output string.

Comment: Assuming the problem is caused by SQL injection, it's actually *easier* to use parameterized queries, using a library like Dapper, eg : `var customers=connection.Query<Customer>("select * from Customers where name=@name",new {name="O'Reily and \"Monty Python\""});`